# WPF app with .NETCore video effect library based on IBasicVideoEffect

Tags: wpf, uwp, .net-core

Is there a way to include a reference to a .NetCore library in a 4.5.2 framework based c# wpf app.  This is a video effects library that is based on the IBasicVideoEffect interface.  I can include the c++ library as a winmd reference, but it complains about the IBasicVideo effect IF when trying to utilize it, and I cannot find a way to include this interface definition in the app since it seems to be UWP only.  I have the app utilizing the runtime and set the target to windows 10 in order to utilize the mediacapture class, but I cannot seem to find a way to access the IBasicVideoEffect definition.

Comment: Please refer the document [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#kGEbFHE3jpWxW827.97).